# Error in Production Application SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

We have SharePoint application running perfectly finr on production since long however from today we are getting error on production on one page , I have traced the log via sharepoint logviewer on production and found the following exception

Caught a thread abort exception in TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest, the exception may be expected. stack trace=   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    at ASP.BLANKWEBPARTPAGE_ASPX_1653093133.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

Application is working fine for users who dont have any task assign however application throw exception for users who have assign tasks

We are using asp.net workflow in this application

Can any one help what is the issue?

Zareen

Answer (score 0):

It seems like someone added erroneous custom blank web part on your task page.

You need to check the code, if there are any blank web part added or not.

Usually people add blank web part into solution just to make the deployable WSP site scoped else feature would not get displayed. BY adding webpart into solution it creates site scoped feature automatically.

If this is the case then you can do any of the following four options to rectify your production environment.

1. Use SharePoint Designer to remove added blank webpart code directly.
2. Redeploy the code after resolving the issue of blank web part
3. If the page is OOB then recreate it.
4. If it is application page then redeploying the old wsp will work.

I hope it will help.